# Trouble taking a subset of one data frame inside of another data frame

Tags: r, for-loop

I’m trying to do two things in the code below.

The first: I’m trying to create subsets of the “regular_season” dataset that are split by season, category, and question. I think that part is correctly done below. Within each subset, I would like to do the second thing.

The second: I have two datasets: one is called “regular_season” and the other is called “championships,” and both have a column called “correct.” In “regular_season,” the “correct” column is 600 entries long and in “championships,” the column is 24 entries long. Within the subsets of the “regular_season” we created above, I am trying to replace the “correct” column in “championships” with a random subset of the “correct” column in “regular_season” that is also 24 entries long. To do all of this, I have tried the code:

```
#First half of the question
regular_season$flag <- with(regular_season, season %in% 
        c('76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83'))
rs_scq_user_ <- split(regular_season, regular_season[c('category', 'question', 
         'flag')], drop = TRUE)


    champ_correct_user_  <- subset(championships, round < 3)
    champ_correct_user_ <- subset(champ_correct_user_, correct %in% champ_correct_user_)
    champ_correct_user_ <- subset(champ_correct_user_, id %in% champ_correct_user_)
  output_champ_correct_user_ <- vector("list", length(champ_correct_user_))
    
for(i in champ_correct_user_) {
    champ_correct_user_[i] <- subset([i], id %in% [i])
    output_champ_correct_user_[[i]] <- champ_correct_user_[i]
}
  
#Second half of the question
regular_season$flag <- with(regular_season, season %in% 
        c('76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83'))
rs_scq_user_ <- split(regular_season, regular_season[c('category', 'question', 
         'flag')], drop = TRUE) 
  
rs_scq_correct_sample_user_ <- regular_season[sample(1:nrow(rs_scq_user_$correct), 24, replace = FALSE),]
  
output_rs_scq_correct_sample_user_ <- vector("list", length(rs_scq_correct_sample_user_))
  
for (i in rs_scq_user) {
    rs_scq_correct_sample_user_[i] <- regular_season[sample(1:nrow([i]$correct), 24, replace = FALSE),]

print(rs_scq_correct_sample_user_[i])
output_rs_scq_correct_sample_user_[[i]] <- rs_scq_correct_sample_user_[i]
}
```

But this is not working. For each user, I would want the code to replace the “correct” column in “championships” with a random subset of the “correct” column in “regular_season” that is 24 entries long. I’m not sure how to do that last part (my code is only to take a random sample of the regular_season’s “correct” column, and I’m not even sure it does that). If anyone can see a way to get the code to work, can you please point out the solution below?

Also, correct me if I'm wrong but putting an "i" in two brackets in a for loop (like "output_rs_scq_correct_sample_user_[[i]] <- rs_scq_correct_sample_user_[i]") saves the loop, right?

EDIT:

For example, if "regular_season$correct" contained

```
12, 
34, 
3, 
56, 
32, 
... 
(595 more entries)
```

and "championships$correct" contained

```
1,
0,
0,
1,
0,
...
(19 more entries)
```

I'm trying to take a random sample of the entries in "regular_season$correct" and use them to replace the entries in "championships$correct." I'm hoping the output would look something like:

```
"championships$correct"
32,
79,
56,
98,
8,
...
(19 more entries)
```

I hope this helps! I'm sorry if it is still a bit unclear, I'm not too great at explaining things, and I find things like this difficult, so I might have still been a bit unclear.

Comment: @akrun of course, I have just done that! I'm really sorry if some parts are still a bit unclear but if I can clarify anything else in any way, please let me know what I can do!

Comment: @akrun yes championships is not split. Also my mistake about the "rs_scq_user" I'll see if I can still write it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are trying to replace the 'correct' column of 'championships' from a `sample` of 'regular_season' 'correct' with the `length` same as the number of rows of 'championships', create an index of rows with `sample`

```
i1 <- sample(nrow(regular_season), size = nrow(championships))
```

Extract the elements of 'correct' based on that index from 'regular_season' data

```
v1 <- regular_season$correct[i1]
```

and assign it to the 'championships' data 'correct'

```
championships$correct <- v1
```

---

This can be written in a single line as well

```
championships$correct <-  with(regular, correct[sample(length(correct),
             size = nrow(championships))])
```

Comment: thank you your answer has helped me greatly, I really appreciate it!

Comment: And thank you for being patient and asking me to clarify my question, I really appreciate that too!